# How to set Image at current Cell (Kingfisher)? Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, kingfisher

I have an `TableView` with custom cells. Label `smiles` contain links.

How can I put Image from link to current ImageView'cell? My code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "ClientCell"
        self.cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? customChatCell

let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] ?? ""
let selectedCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? customChatCell

***

if text.range(of:"smiles") != nil {
            let url = URL(string: text)
            self.cell![indexPath.row].smile.kf.setImage(with: url)
        } 

***
}
```

not working. I'm getting error for line `self.cell![indexPath.row].smile.kf.setImage(with: url)`

> Type 'customChatCell' has no subscript members

I'm using Kingfisher. If I use code

```
self.cell.smile.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

image putting into all cells, not for current.

**Please help me fix it.**

Comment: Why do you use the property `self.cell` and not simply `let cell = ... dequeue ...`? Also, what do you want do achieve with `cell![indexPath.row]`? Looks like an array access to me.

Comment: I want simple download image from url contains in label (let text) and put it to ImageView smile (to current cell). Sorry for noob question

Comment: Could you please let us know what do you mean by current cell?

Comment: In my TableView non-static count of cells. All cells contains text-label and imageview. But only in few cells text-label contains link for image. I want to put image from text-label to cell, which contains link in text-label. Not for all, only for this few cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove keeping the `cell` reference at `class` level. Your `cellForRow` should look like this,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let identifier = "ClientCell"
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? customChatCell

       let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] ?? ""
       if text.range(of:"smiles") != nil {
            let url = URL(string: text)
            cell.smile.kf.setImage(with: url)
       } else {
           // Reset image to nil here if it has no url
           cell.smile.image = nil  
       }
}
```

Remember, you are using a single `UIView`(i.e, `customChatCell`) for each cell in `UITableView` so when you dequeue a cell it's your responsibility to update/reset the `UI` elements according to your data for each cell.

Comment: In different cells text-label can contains different links. With your code image from last link putting into all cells.

Comment: Because i don't know what is `message`? If `message` is same for all cells then you should see the same `image`. You should print `text` and verify you are getting different `text` for each `cell`.